# Results between different hours and same day SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, datetime, where-clause

I need  your help, I have this.

```
AND Fecha BETWEEN '2020-05-21 06:00:00' AND '2020-05-21 15:30:00'
```

and it's working,,, but I want to use something like this

```
AND Fecha BETWEEN Fecha '06:00:00' AND Fecha '15:30:00'
```

And doesn't work,,, can you help me? I want to have the restult between diferent hour but same day, using Fecha.

[image]

[image]

For you help, Thanks

Comment: I don't understand your question. Please [edit] it to show some sample data and results.

Comment: "And doesn't work" will not help us help you!  Please explain what "doesn't work" mean?  No result???  Wrong result???

Comment: "I want to have the result between different hour but same day"  Then use your first query.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `time()` to extract the time portion of a `datetime` or `timestamp`, and then use in for comparison:

```
and time(fecha) between '06:00:00' and '15:30:00'
```

Note: I am unsure that you want to include the upper bound; presumably, you could use an half-open interval instead:

```
and time(fecha) >= '06:00:00' and time(fecha) < '15:30:00'
```

Comment: Good call on the half-open interval.

Comment: Thanks, I tried with your answer and not working,,, I need see the results between that hours of the same day.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you want records from all calendar dates with times between 06:00 and 15:30.

Try this

```
AND TIME(Fecha) BETWEEN '06:00:00' AND '15:30:00'
```

If you compare `00:06:00` directly to a DATETIME or TIMESTAMP column, you actually compare  `0000-00-00 06:00:00`. That was long ago.

Comment: Thanks, I tried with your answer and not working,,, I need see the results between that hours of the same day.

Answer (score 1):

If you want the results for the current date:

```
WHERE DATE(FETCHA) = CURRENT_DATE AND TIME(FETCHA) BETWEEN '06:00:00' AND '15:30:00'
```

or for any other date:

```
WHERE DATE(FETCHA) = ? AND TIME(FETCHA) BETWEEN '06:00:00' AND '15:30:00'
```

replace `?` with the date that you want the results.